# Enumerate all possible dataclass instances (with enum and bool fields only)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

Basically I need following. I have a *python3* [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) or [NamedTuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=namedtuple#typing.NamedTuple), with only `enum` and `bool` fields. E.g.:

```py
from enum import Enum, auto
from typing import NamedTuple

class MyEnum(Enum):
    v1 = auto()
    v2 = auto()
    v3 = auto()


class MyStateDefinition(NamedTuple):
    a: MyEnum
    b: bool
```

Is here any good known solution to enumerate all possible non-equal instances of such a dataclass? *(Example above has 6 possible non-equal instances)*.

Perhaps it is not a `dataclass` I should use, but something else. Or should I play with such things like [`dataclasses.fields`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields) directly?

I imagine it as some table generator which accepts a `namedtuple` or `dataclass` as an input parameter and produces all possible values.

```py
table = DataTable(MyStateDefinition)
for item in table:
    # Use items somehow
    print(item.a)
    print(item.b)
```

Why do I need it? I just have some state definition which consists of enums and bools. I believe it could be implemented as a bitmask. But when it comes to extending your bitmask with new values, it turns out to be a nightmare. Afterall, bitmasks seem to be a non-pythonic way of doing things.

Currently I have to use an implementation of my own. But perhaps I'm reinventing the wheel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using enums, with the data-tuples as the enum-members' value (an `Enum`/`NamedTuple` hybrid, if you will). The `_ignore_` attribute is used to prevent certain names in the class namespace from being converted into enum members.

```
from itertools import product
from enum import Enum

class Data(Enum):
    _ignore_ = "Data", "myenum_member", "truthiness"

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.value[0]

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.value[1]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Data(a={self.a!r}, b={self.b!r})'

    Data = vars()
    for myenum_member, truthiness in product(MyEnum, (True, False)):
        Data[f'{myenum_member.name}_{truthiness}'] = (myenum_member, truthiness)
```

You should be able to iterate through the resulting enum class just as you desire.

This use of enums is similar to the ["time period" example](https://docs.python.org/3.11/howto/enum.html#timeperiod) in the Enum HOWTO section of the docs.

---

**Generating this kind of table dynamically**

If you want to generate this kind of table dynamically, you could do something like this, (ab)using metaclasses. I've shown example usages for how you would use this `DataTable` class in the docstrings. (For some reason, using `typing.get_type_hints` in a doctest seems to cause the `doctest` module to error out, but the examples do work if you try them yourself in an interactive terminal.) Rather than special-casing `bool`, as you did in your answer, I decided to special-case `typing.Literal`, as it seemed like a more extensible option (and `bool` can just be spelled as `typing.Literal[True, False]`).

```
from __future__ import annotations
from itertools import product
from enum import Enum, EnumMeta

from typing import (
    Iterable,
    Mapping,
    cast,
    Protocol,
    get_type_hints,
    Any,
    get_args,
    get_origin,
    Literal,
    TypeVar,
    Union,
    Optional
)

D = TypeVar('D')
T = TypeVar('T')


class DataTableFactory(EnumMeta):
    """A helper class for making data tables (an implementation detail of `DataTable`)."""

    _CLS_BASES = (Enum,)

    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(  # type: ignore[override]
            metacls,
            cls_name: str,
            fields: Mapping[str, Iterable[Any]]
    ) -> dict[str, Any]:

        cls_dict = cast(
            dict[str, Any],
            super().__prepare__(cls_name, metacls._CLS_BASES)
        )

        for i, field in enumerate(fields.keys()):
            cls_dict[field] = property(fget=lambda self, i=i: self.value[i])  # type: ignore[misc]

        for p in product(*fields.values()):
            cls_dict['_'.join(map(str, p))] = p

        def __repr__(self: Enum) -> str:
            contents = ', '.join(
                f'{field}={getattr(self, field)!r}'
                for field in fields
            )
            return f'{cls_name}Member({contents})'

        cls_dict['__repr__'] = __repr__
        return cls_dict

    @classmethod
    def make_datatable(
            metacls,
            cls_name: str,
            *,
            fields: Mapping[str, Iterable[Any]],
            doc: Optional[str] = None
    ) -> type[Enum]:
        """Create a new data table"""

        cls_dict = metacls.__prepare__(cls_name, fields)
        new_cls = metacls.__new__(metacls, cls_name, metacls._CLS_BASES, cls_dict)
        new_cls.__module__ = __name__

        if doc is None:
            all_attrs = '\n'.join(
                f'    {f"{attr_name}: ":<{(max(map(len, fields)) + 3)}}one of {attr_val!r}'
                for attr_name, attr_val in fields.items()
            )

            fields_len = len(fields)

            doc = (
                f'An enum-like data table.\n\n'
                f'All members of this data table have {fields_len} '
                f'read-only attribute{"s" if fields_len > 1 else ""}:\n'
                f'{all_attrs}\n\n'
                f'----------------------------------------------------------------------'
            )

        new_cls.__doc__ = doc
        return cast(type[Enum], new_cls)

    def __repr__(cls) -> str:
        return f"<Data table '{cls.__name__}'>"

    def index_of(cls: Iterable[D], member: D) -> int:
        """Get the index of a member in the list of members."""
        return list(cls).index(member)

    def get(
            cls: Iterable[D],
            /,
            *,
            default_: Optional[T] = None,
            **kwargs: Any
    ) -> Union[D, T, None]:
        """Return instance for given arguments set.
        Return `default_` if no member matches those arguments.
        """

        it = (
            member for member in cls
            if all((getattr(member, key) == val) for key, val in kwargs.items())
        )

        return next(it, default_)

    def __dir__(cls) -> list[str]:
        # By defining __dir__, we make methods defined in this class
        # discoverable by the interactive help() function in the REPL
        return cast(list[str], super().__dir__()) + ['index_of', 'get']


class TypedStructProto(Protocol):
    """In order to satisfy this interface, a type must have an __annotations__ dict."""
    __annotations__: dict[str, Union[Iterable[Any], type[Literal[True]]]]


class DataTableMeta(type):
    """Metaclass for `DataTable`."""
    __call__ = DataTableFactory.make_datatable  # type: ignore[assignment]


class DataTable(metaclass=DataTableMeta):
    """A mechanism to create 'data table enumerations' -- not really a class at all!

    Example usage
    -------------
    >>> Cars = DataTable('Cars', fields={'make': ('Toyota', 'Audi'), 'colour': ('Red', 'Blue')})
    >>> Cars
    <Data table 'Cars'>
    >>> list(Cars)
    [CarsMember(make=Toyota, colour=Red), CarsMember(make=Toyota, colour=Blue), CarsMember(make=Audi, colour=Red), CarsMember(make=Audi, colour=Blue)]
    >>> Cars.get(make='Audi', colour='Red')
    CarsMember(make=Audi, colour=Red)
    >>> Cars.index_of(_)
    2
    """

    @classmethod
    def from_struct(cls, cls_name: str, *, struct: type[TypedStructProto], doc: Optional[str] = None) -> type[Enum]:
        """Make a DataTable from a "typed struct" -- e.g. a dataclass, NamedTuple or TypedDict.

        Example usage (works the same way with dataclasses and TypedDicts)
        -------------------------------------------------------------------
        >>> from enum import Enum, auto
        >>> from typing import NamedTuple, Literal
        >>> class E(Enum):
        ...     v1 = auto()
        ...     v2 = auto()
        ...     v3 = auto()
        ...
        >>> class BoolsEndEnums(NamedTuple):
        ...     a: E
        ...     b: Literal[True, False]
        ...
        >>> BoolsEndEnumsTable = DataTable.from_struct('BoolsEndEnumsTable', struct=BoolsEndEnums)
        >>> list(BoolsEndEnumsTable)
        [BoolsEndEnumsTableMember(a=E.v1, b=True), BoolsEndEnumsTableMember(a=E.v1, b=False), BoolsEndEnumsTableMember(a=E.v2, b=True), BoolsEndEnumsTableMember(a=E.v2, b=False), BoolsEndEnumsTableMember(a=E.v3, b=True), BoolsEndEnumsTableMember(a=E.v3, b=False)]
        """

        fields = get_type_hints(struct)

        for field_name, field_val in fields.items():
            if get_origin(field_val) is Literal:
                fields[field_name] = get_args(field_val)

        return cast(type[Enum], cls(cls_name, fields=fields, doc=doc))  # type: ignore[call-arg]
```

I've had to do some "interesting" things with the type hints, but MyPy is [sort of happy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=0d6a4df325c3611bf0b214299a1505dc) with all this.

Comment: I love your idea with `product` and dynamic vars definition. Perhaps I'll combine my and your approaches in nearest future. Thanks!

Comment: @StepanDyatkovskiy I've added some ideas for how you could generate this kind of table dynamically. Hope it's helpful; was a fun piece of code to write :)

Answer (score 1):

Also posting implementation of my own. Not ideal, I had to use some protected members.

Usage:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple
from datatable import DataTable

class BoolsEndEnums(NamedTuple):
    a: E
    b: bool


tbl = DataTable(BoolsEndEnums)

item = tbl[0]

print(item.a) # a is v1
print(item.b) # b is False
```

See `test_datatable.py`, `_test_cls` for more usage examples.

**datatable.py**

```py
import collections
import dataclasses
from collections import Iterable
from enum import Enum
from typing import Union, Any, Tuple, Iterator, get_type_hints, NamedTuple


def is_cls_namedtuple(cls):
    return issubclass(cls, tuple) and hasattr(cls, "_fields")


class DataTable(Iterable):
    def __init__(self, data_cls):
        self._table = []
        self._index = {}
        self._rindex = {}
        self._named_tuple_cls = None

        fields = None

        if dataclasses.is_dataclass(data_cls):
            fields = [f.name for f in dataclasses.fields(data_cls)]
            self._named_tuple_cls = collections.namedtuple(
                f"{data_cls.__name__}_immutable",
                fields
            )
        elif is_cls_namedtuple(data_cls):
            self._named_tuple_cls = data_cls
            fields = data_cls._fields
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                "Only dataclasses and NamedTuple subclasses are supported."
            )

        hints = get_type_hints(data_cls)

        self._build_table([], [(f, hints[f]) for f in fields])

    def index_of(self, instance):
        """
        Returns record index of given instance in table.
        :param instance:
        :return:
        """
        index = self._as_index(instance)
        return self._rindex.get(index)

    def get(self, **kw):
        """
        Returns instance for given arguments set
        :param kw:
        :return:
        """
        index = self._as_index(kw)
        return self._table[self._rindex[index]]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._table)

    def __getitem__(self, i: Union[int, slice]):
        return self._table[i]

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator:
        return self._table.__iter__()

    def _build_table(self, defined_fields, remained_fields):
        if not remained_fields:
            instance = self._named_tuple_cls(**dict(defined_fields))
            item_id = len(self._table)
            self._index[item_id] = instance
            self._rindex[self._as_index(defined_fields)] = item_id
            self._table.append(instance)
            return

        next_name, next_type = remained_fields[0]
        remained_fields = remained_fields[1:]

        if issubclass(next_type, Enum):
            for v in next_type:
                self._build_table(
                    defined_fields + [(next_name, v)],
                    remained_fields
                )
            return

        if next_type is bool:
            self._build_table(
                defined_fields + [(next_name, False)],
                remained_fields
            )
            self._build_table(
                defined_fields + [(next_name, True)],
                remained_fields
            )
            return

        raise ValueError(f"Got unexpected dataclass field type: {next_type}")

    @staticmethod
    def _as_index(v: Union[Any, Tuple[str, Any]]):
        items = None
        if dataclasses.is_dataclass(v):
            items = dataclasses.asdict(v).items()
        elif is_cls_namedtuple(type(v)):
            items = v._asdict().items()
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            items = v.items()
        else:
            assert isinstance(v, collections.Sequence)
            items = v

        return tuple(sorted(items, key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

**test_datatable.py**

```py
import dataclasses
from enum import Enum, auto
from typing import NamedTuple

import pytest

from dataclass_utils import DataTable


class E(Enum):
    v1 = auto()
    v2 = auto()
    v3 = auto()


@dataclasses.dataclass
class BoolsEndEnums:
    a: E
    b: bool


class BoolsEndEnumsNamedTuple(NamedTuple):
    a: E
    b: bool


@dataclasses.dataclass
class HugeSetOfValues:
    a: int
    b: bool


class NotSupportedCls:
    pass


def _test_cls(cls):
    tbl = DataTable(cls)

    first = cls(E.v1, False)
    last = cls(E.v3, True)

    expected_num_entries = 6

    assert tbl.index_of(first) == 0
    assert tbl.index_of(last) == (expected_num_entries - 1)
    assert len(tbl) == expected_num_entries

    actual_third = tbl.get(a=E.v2, b=False)
    assert actual_third.a == E.v2
    assert actual_third.b is False

    actual_forth = tbl[3]
    assert actual_forth.a == E.v2
    assert actual_forth.b is True

    items = [item for item in tbl]

    actual_fifth = items[4]
    assert actual_fifth.a == E.v3
    assert actual_fifth.b is False

    # Test that we can't change result
    with pytest.raises(AttributeError):
        tbl[0].a = E.v2


def test_dataclass():
    _test_cls(BoolsEndEnums)


def test_namedtuple():
    _test_cls(BoolsEndEnumsNamedTuple)


def test_datatable_neg():
    """
    Generic negative tests
    """
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        DataTable(HugeSetOfValues)

    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        DataTable(NotSupportedCls)
```

Comment: I wouldn't feel bad about using "protected" methods of namedtuples — those methods only start with a leading underscore to prevent potential conflicts with fields that might have a similar name. Raymond Hettinger, the creator of namedtuples, has said that the design choice was a mistake and that those methods wouldn't start with leading underscores if he were to rewrite the class from scratch https://lwn.net/Articles/731045/